# How do I get a continuation token for a bulk INSERT on Azure Cosmos DB?

Tags: stored-procedures, azure-cosmosdb

I want to upload a CSV file that represents 10k documents to be added to my Cosmos DB collection in a manner that's fast and atomic. I have a stored procedure like the following pseudo-code:

```
function createDocsFromCSV(csv_text) {
    function parse(txt) { // ... parsing code here ... }

    var collection = getContext().getCollection();
    var response = getContext().getResponse();

    var docs_to_create = parse(csv_text);
    for(var ii=0; ii<docs_to_create.length; ii++) {
        var accepted = collection.createDocument(collection.getSelfLink(),
                                                    docs_to_create[ii],
                                                    function(err, doc_created) {
                                                        if(err) throw new Error('Error' + err.message);
                                                    });
        if(!accepted) {
            throw new Error('Timed out creating document ' + ii);
        }
    }
}
```

When I run it, the stored procedure creates about 1200 documents before timing out (and therefore rolling back and not creating any documents).

Previously I had success updating (instead of creating) thousands of documents in a stored procedure using continuation tokens and this answer as guidance: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34761098/277504. But after searching documentation (e.g. https://azure.github.io/azure-documentdb-js-server/Collection.html) I don't see a way to get continuation tokens from creating documents like I do for querying documents.

Is there a way to take advantage of stored procedures for bulk document creation?

Comment: Hi, does my answer helps you?

Answer (score 2):

It’s important to note that stored procedures have bounded execution, in which all operations must complete within the server specified request timeout duration. If an operation does not complete with that time limit, the transaction is automatically rolled back.

In order to simplify development to handle time limits, all CRUD (Create, Read, Update, and Delete) operations return a Boolean value that represents whether that operation will complete. This Boolean value can be used a signal to wrap up execution and for implementing a continuation based model to resume execution (this is illustrated in our code samples below). More details, please refer to the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/programming#bounded-execution).

The bulk-insert stored procedure provided above implements the continuation model by returning the number of documents successfully created.

***pseudo-code:***

```
function createDocsFromCSV(csv_text,count) {
    function parse(txt) { // ... parsing code here ... }

    var collection = getContext().getCollection();
    var response = getContext().getResponse();

    var docs_to_create = parse(csv_text);
    for(var ii=count; ii<docs_to_create.length; ii++) {
        var accepted = collection.createDocument(collection.getSelfLink(),
                                                    docs_to_create[ii],
                                                    function(err, doc_created) {
                                                        if(err) throw new Error('Error' + err.message);
                                                    });
        if(!accepted) {
            getContext().getResponse().setBody(count);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you could check the output document count on the client side and re-run the stored procedure with the `count` parameter to create the remaining set of documents until the count larger than the length of `csv_text`.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: This sounds like it might work, and I expect to try it this week. From what I understand, this solution will not be atomic, since it will be creating new documents in the collection even when the total number hasn't been reached. In my first tests, 1200 documents were queued for entry, but 0 were committed, but I didn't think to keep resubmitting the function again and again. I'll post back once I've tried that.